# LINQ no longer has intellisense in views

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, intellisense

Ever since we upgraded to .Net 4.0 and VS2010 (from 3.5 and 2008) we can no longer get intellisense on LINQ to kick in when working in our views. Before the upgrade everything was working fine, but after the upgrade it's actually listed as an error when we try to use things like .Where() on a collection. Oddly it will compile fine and run, but this makes it very annoying when writing LINQ in our views.

Specifically the errors list things like "System.Collections.Generic.List does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting fist argument of type System.Collections.Generic.List could be found".

I've tried adding the System.Data.Linq assembly and the System.Core assembly to the web config with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've had this. No idea why, but interesting none the less to find out why. It wasn't with Linq, but Intellisense in general. Also, as a side note, Linq in a view? Urgh.

Comment: i'm with Finglas on this one,   you shouldn't really be using linq in your views!   

does other intellisence work?

Comment: Yes, other intellisence works fine, it just can't seem to find the LINQ methods.

The LINQ in the views is pretty minimal, but you're correct, it's something we've been trying to avoid. We just don't want this upgrade issue to be the thing that forces us to refactor (would rather do it over time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the upgrade was performed it forgot to add the attribute of `targetFramework` to the  `compilation` element in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Add that to your web.config and you should regain intellisense again in your views.